# Non LSD oil in a LSD

Tags: oil, differential, lsd

I recently changed all the oils in my land cruiser BJ40, including the rear differential which has a limited slip dif with apparently something called a power trax traction system. I put in normal gear oil 80W-90 GL5. (not LSD oil) Is it a problem?

Answer (score 5):

It may not be apparent right away but may cause issues later on. The Limited Slip  Differential contains clutches. They require oil with an additive that allows the clutches to operate correctly. Check the container that the oil came in, it should say Limited Slip/ Posi-trac compatible. It may be in small print on the back of the bottle. If it doesn't, you could purchase a small container of the additive separately and add it the differential. It may cost almost as much as the oil that contains the additive, but it beats draining and refilling.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently it is NOT a LSD but an open dif with a power trax locker system. The container was plain 80-90W gear oil.